# How can I only assign a previous value to state of my datepicker if the new one is invalid?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, react-usememo

I am dealing with a bug in a library I'm using that will sometimes create invalid values that my code will need, crashing the page. I would like to only apply that new value (the result of `useDateRangePickerState`) if it is valid. If not, I do not want to assign that value to my state. How can I do this?

```
export const DateRangePicker: FC<AriaDateRangePickerProps<DateValue>> = memo((props) => {

  const defaultNowTime = {timeValue}
  const [nowTime, setNowTime] = useState(defaultNowTime);

  const newstate = useDateRangePickerState({
    ...props,
    defaultValue: {
      start: defaultNowTime.set({ second: 0, minute: 0, millisecond: 0, hour: 0 }),
      end: defaultNowTime
    },
    hideTimeZone: true,
    shouldCloseOnSelect: false,
  });

  //once a valid 'newstate' is created, cache it with useMemo here?
  //cachedOldState = ...
  //only use the valid to assign state if its valid! *******************
  const state = (newstate is valid) ? newstate : cachedOldState
...
```

Comment: Is the `useDateRangePickerState` hook part of the library or is it something that you control?  If you control it then you would want to stop invalid values there before they bubble up. I'm really confused by this code.  `defaultNowTime` is stored in state so isn't it a mutation of state to call `defaultNowTime.set` in your `defaultValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `useDateRangePickerState` hook part is something that you control then you will want to stop invalid values there before they bubble up. But if it's part of the buggy library then you can make it work.

You've got the right idea here:

```
//once a valid 'newstate' is created, cache it with useMemo here?
//cachedOldState = ...
//only use the valid to assign state if its valid! *******************
const state = (newstate is valid) ? newstate : cachedOldState
```

We need to store the previous valid state somewhere.  I would use a `useState` for that.

Then we need to check changes from the date picker and see if they are valid.  I recommend a `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `newstate`.  This will run every time that the `newstate` changes.

If the `newstate` is valid we will call `setState` and that way we keep our "previous valid state" value in sync.

```
const newstate = useDateRangePickerState({ /* ... */ });

const [validDate, setValidDate] = useState(initialValue);

useEffect(() => {
   if (isValid(newstate)) {
       setValidDate(newstate);
   }
}, [newstate]);
```

---

As a sidenote, I'm really confused by the code in your question. `defaultNowTime` is stored in state so isn't it a mutation of state to call `defaultNowTime.set` in the `defaultValue`?

Comment: thank you for your response! This is helpful. Just to confirm, what is 'initialValue'? Is that the value that I had stored in useMemo in the previous render?

And yes, unfortunately it is from a buggy library

Comment: The `initialValue` is whatever the date range is on the first render.  Probably that's the `defaultValue`?  But I don't know how the library works.

Comment: Hmmm.... I guess if you switch the order of the `useState` and the `useDateRangePickerState` hooks then you can get the initial state from the picker. `const [validDate, setValidDate] = useState(newstate)`.  But you won't have validated it.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you that makes sense! Now the error I am seeing is 'react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function'. Will I need to move these hooks outside of my component declaration since I use 'memo'?

Comment: No, the `memo` should not make a difference.  Something else is wrong.  Sounds like you have one hook inside of another?